# Loop through text file, amend & write new file PHP

Tags: php

I have a file called `test.txt`. It has multiple lines of text in it like thus:

```
Test Data:
Tester 2 Data:
Tests 3 Data:
```

I would like to have a PHP script that opens this file, strips ALL of the text before the word `Data:` on each row and outputs the result:

```
Data:
Data:
Data:
```

My **PHP** so far:

```
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data = fread($myfile,filesize("test.txt"));

// foreach line do this
$line = strstr($data,"Data:");
//append $line to newtest.txt
// endforeach

fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to open and loop over a file line by line.

As you are removing everything before `Data:`, based on your test data supplied (which is all I have to go on), we only need to know the number of lines. So, we can use `count()` to get that information.

Then construct the new data as a variable, and finally write that variable to a (new) file using [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Using `trim()` will remove the last extra line return.

```
$raw = file("./test.txt");
$lineCount = count($raw);
$newFile = null;
do {
    $newFile .= "Data:\r\n";
} while(--$lineCount > 0);
file_put_contents('./test-new.txt',trim($newFile));
```

Edit:
As *Don't Panic* says in the comment below, you could use [`str_repeat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) to even remove the `do while` loop.

Here is that version with the `count()` moved in-line as well:

```
$raw = file("./test.txt");
$newFile = str_repeat("Data:\r\n",count($raw));
file_put_contents('./test-new.txt',trim($newFile));
```

Comment: Wow, @Tigger - incredible. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Happy to have helped.

Comment: I think you could replace the loop with str_repeat if you like.

Comment: @Don'tPanic : Yep, spot on. Updated answer.